# How to manage SSO, Chrome Extension and Google Play Store account under the same roof

Tags: google-play, store

We have app in Google Play store and we are using *xyz@gmail.com*
 gmail account for Google Play store to publish app in Google store.

Now we have to release one Chrome extension with same *xyz@gmail.com* gmail account and we also have `SSO` account.

Now, is there any way to manage all above things under one single roof like one company. Because `SSO`, chrome extension and app in google store all are related to each other.

I didn't find any way where I can manage all three things as one account. For everything I need to open different websites.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to go to the different websites. The reason? It's a bit like saying why do I have to go to different websites for Google Docs, Google Maps and Gmail. They too are the same account, and related to each other, but are different things. The same goes for Chrome extensions and Apps.